# Parrallelism and concurrency in multiprocess and multithreading

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, coroutine

Hello I'm studying Operating Sysyem. I recognize the difference between parrallelism and concurrency but I still wonder at some point so I wanna get some help thank you!

1. What I know is that threads are parallel in multiThreading but there are contexts switching among threads. How does it possible? Does that happen when they approach to shared resources?
2. In case of 4cores 8threads. Are processes running parrallel or concurrently? If they run concurrently, processes switch each other but only 2 threads are running at once at any time in cpu right?
3. I heard coroutine is concurrent. Which means it doesnt share any resources but how can race conditions still happen there?

Comment: The questions are pretty unclear to me. What do you mean by "*Does that happen when they approach to shared resources?*" or even "*Which means it doesnt share any resources but how can race conditions still happen there?*" ? More specifically the term resource is ambiguous (I do not see a clear relation with concurrency).

Answer (score 0):

1. Context switching is required, because usually we execute more threads than we have CPU cores. And yes, this often happens when the currently running thread has to wait for something (I guess this is what you meant by "shared resource"), then the thread goes to sleep and another is awaken. But context switching could also happen at almost any time - OS scheduler is responsible for sharing CPU cores between threads in the way that one or few threads don't consume all resources.
2. "Do processes are running parrallel or concurrent?" - processes or rather threads? Threads run both concurrently and in parallel, but the parallelism is limited to 4. And no, there is only one thread running in a specific core at a time (I ignore hyper-threading here).
3. I have no idea what do you mean here. Coroutines are concurrent in a similar way to threads and the resource sharing pose a similar challenge when using them.